# Magento 1.9 sendTransactional() doesn't include CSS from email template

Tags: magento-1.9, transactional-mail, send-mail

I'm using **sendTransactional()** to send emails programmatically. All working fine besides the following line in the email template is not included

```
  {{inlinecss file="email-inline.css"}}
```

Any fixes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it out. It has to include ->setDesignConfig()

So the following code will include CSS file when sending out emails with sendTransactional().

```
    Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
        ->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $storeId))
        ->sendTransactional($templateId, $sender, $recepientEmail, $recepientName, $vars, $storeId)
    ;
```